# Neighbouring feature that share more than 2 vertices in Atlas

Tags: qgis, symbology, atlas

Is there a way to filter polygons that share more than 2 vertices with a feature?

I have a problem where I have a layer being controlled by Atlas, and I would like to show on Atlas only the coverage feature and the neighbouring features that share more than 2 vertices with it.

Up until now I can achieve what is in the first image using `touches($geometry, @atlas_geometry)` in the filter in rule-based symbology. But I wanted something like in the second image. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `ruled based symbology` filter, you can compute the intersection and keep the ones having more than 1 point

`num_points(intersection($geometry,@atlas_geometry))>1`

Comment: That exactly what I needed! Thank you!!